# Maximum sum such that no two elements are adjacent

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Now the available solution every where is to have an *include* and *exclude* sum . At the end `max` of these two will give me the output.

Now initially I was having difficulty to understand this algorithm and I thought why not going in a simple way.

Algo:
Loop over the array by increasing array pointer two at a time

1. Calculate the *odd* positioned element `sum` in the array
2. Calculate the *even* positioned element `sum`

At the end, take `max` of this two `sum`.

in that way, I think complexity will be reduced to half `O(n/2)`

Is this algo *correct*?

Comment: No this will not work.Why? because not being adjacent doesn't mean that  all the numbers have to be only in odd or even indexes. Consider `[1, -2 -3, 100]`. The solution is the `1 + 100` which is a odd and even index

Comment: @LalitVerma I implemented and I arrived here because I didn't find solutions as Subhadeep

Answer (score 3):

It's a case of dynamic programming. The algorithm is:

1. Do not take (*sum up*) any non-positive items
2. For positive numbers, split the problem in two: try *taking* and *skiping* the item and return the maximum of these choices:

Let's show the 2nd step, imagine we are given:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 125, -8, 9]
```

`1` is positive, that's why

```
take_sum = max(1 + max_sum([3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 125, -8, 9])) // we take "1"
skip_sum = max_sum([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 125, -8, 9])       // we skip "1" 
max_sum =  max(take_sum, skip_sum)
```

**C# implementation** (the simplest code in order to show the naked idea, no further optimization):

```
private static int BestSum(int[] array, int index) {
  if (index >= array.Length)
    return 0;

  if (array[index] <= 0)
    return BestSum(array, index + 1);

  int take = array[index] + BestSum(array, index + 2);
  int skip = BestSum(array, index + 1);

  return Math.Max(take, skip);
}

private static int BestSum(int[] array) {
  return BestSum(array, 0);
}
```

**Test:**

```
Console.WriteLine(BestSum(new int[] { 1, -2, -3, 100 }));
Console.WriteLine(BestSum(new int[] { 100, 8, 10, 20, 7 }))
```

**Outcome:**

```
101        
120
```

Please, check, that your *initial algorithm* returns `98` and `117` which are *suboptimal* sums.

**Edit:** In real life you may want to add some *optimization*, e.g. *memoization* and special cases tests:

```
private static Dictionary<int, int> s_Memo = new Dictionary<int, int>();

private static int BestSum(int[] array, int index) {
  if (index >= array.Length)
    return 0;

  int result;

  if (s_Memo.TryGetValue(index, out result)) // <- Memoization
    return result;

  if (array[index] <= 0) 
    return BestSum(array, index + 1);

  // Always take, when the last item to choose or when followed by non-positive item
  if (index >= array.Length - 1 || array[index + 1] <= 0) {
    result = array[index] + BestSum(array, index + 2);
  }
  else {
    int take = array[index] + BestSum(array, index + 2);
    int skip = BestSum(array, index + 1);

    result = Math.Max(take, skip);
  }

  s_Memo.Add(index, result); // <- Memoization

  return result;
}

private static int BestSum(int[] array) {
  s_Memo.Clear();

  return BestSum(array, 0);
}
```

**Test:**

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  Random gen = new Random(0); // 0 - random, by repeatable (to reproduce the same result)

  int[] test = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 10000)
    .Select(i => gen.Next(100))
    .ToArray();

  int evenSum = test.Where((v, i) => i % 2 == 0).Sum();
  int oddSum = test.Where((v, i) => i % 2 != 0).Sum();
  int suboptimalSum = Math.Max(evenSum, oddSum); // <- Your initial algorithm
  int result = BestSum(test);

  Console.WriteLine(
    $"odd: {oddSum} even: {evenSum} suboptimal: {suboptimalSum} actual: {result}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
  odd: 246117 even: 247137 suboptimal: 247137 actual: 290856
```

Comment: I like this answer very much! Would you recommend any resource that talks about more dynamic programming examples?

Comment: @simo: Well, dynamic programming (sometimes it's called smart recurse) is well known programming method; there are a lot books on it, say, http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/03-dynprog.pdf

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, differently will check that book

Answer (score 0):

dynamic programming inclusion exclusion approach is correct your algorithm would not work for test cases like 3 2 7 10 in this test case the two elements we take are 3 10 and sum is 13 instead of 3,7 or 2,10.may you understand what i am saying and for further clarity code is below

**Java Implementation**

```
public int maxSum(int arr[]) {   // array must contain +ve elements only
 int excl = 0;
 int incl = arr[0];
 for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
   int temp = incl;
   incl = Math.max(excl + arr[i], incl);
   excl = temp;
 }
 return incl;
}
```